# Application to solve for Fourier series coefficients?

Tags: matlab, fourier

Does anyone know a way to solve for Fourier series coefficients using Matlab, WolframAlpha, random web app, etc.? For example if I wanted to solve for and plot the Fourier series coefficients for the function x(t) = cos(100*pi*t) + sin(200*pi*t)? I'm just learning this material in my signals course and looking for a way to check my answers.

Comment: You do not need software to solve this problem. If you understand   the material, you can solve this by inspection.

Comment: That's my problem, I'm very shaky with the material and have many problems to solve so I wanted to see if I could check my answers to find out if I'm going about the problems the right way. My biggest problem is I only have a single example to go by and all the ones I can find online solve by integration rather than inspection.

Answer (score 2):

A Fourier series has the form

$$x(t)=a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left( a_n\cos(\frac{2\pi{}nx}{P}) + b_n\sin(\frac{2\pi{}nx}{P}) \right)$$

Can you find some choices of \$a_n\$, \$b_n\$, and \$P\$  that makes this sum turn into the function you're trying to create without doing any calculation at all?

Comment: Well, I guess if a_n = b_ n = 1, but I haven't seen any of these variables used besides a_n in my course yet. I also am not sure how I could pick the same value of P that would give 100*pi*t for the cos and 200*pi*t for the sin.

Comment: Hint: \$n/P\$ changes in each term of the sum.

Comment: Hint 2: You should have \$a_n=0\$ and \$b_n=0\$ except for two particular values of \$n\$.

Comment: for n = 1 and 2 and P = 1/50 and 1/100? This stuff is very confusing ;/

Comment: \$P\$ is just one number, it can't be two different things in the same series. But \$1/0.01=100\$ and \$2/0.01=200\$, if I have to spoon feed you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [wxMaxima](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxmaxima/). Is a symbolic manipulation package, well documented. With wxMaxima, you can obtain integrals, numeric and symbolic.